# Uncertainty in position of an electron in a cube

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I was solving a question which asked the uncertainty in velocity of an electron trapped in a cube of length x.

Well in the solution they have taken the uncertainty in position to be length of the body diagonal, my doubt is why is the length of the body diagonal the uncertainty, or is the solution wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this answer was just trying to get the order of magnitude - and not trying to do a precise calculation, and so taking the side length $x$, or the diagonal length, or anything, would have been fine. If I wanted to do this precisely, I would instead say - the uncertainty in the $x$ component of momentum is at least:
$$
\sigma_{p_x}\sigma_x\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}
$$
For $\sigma_x$, I would note that the maximum uncertainty in $x$ is if the electron is a uniform distribution, which gives a $\sigma_x=x/2\sqrt{3}$ (the standard deviation of a uniform distribution). Then I have
$$
\sigma_{p_x}\geq\frac{\sqrt{3}\hbar}{x}
$$
This calculates just the momentum uncertainty in each direction, and I think that's all there is to be said about this. I tried working out some kind of sensible standard deviation of the total momentum, but I kept running into shaky BS arguments. So I'll stop here.

Comment: Yes it's normal for momentum. Formally, the standard deviation is infinite for a when you take the Fourier transform of the uniform, compact supported wave function.

Comment: Oh damn good point. The fourier transform of the square wave is $\sim\sin(x)/x$. Then the expectation value of momentum squared will be $\sim\int\sin^2(x)=\infty$. I suppose this is where the $\geq$ in the uncertainty principle comes into play. Unless we're talking about gaussians, it's $\sigma_x\sigma_p>\hbar/2$. I guess in all my effort to be nice and precise about what distribution I chose I actually made the answer worse. Go ahead and downvote if someone has a better answer - I don't want to fully reformulate my answer. Only the first paragraph about orders of magnitude remains valid.

Comment: There is actually nothing wrong with your answer (plus I never downvote...). Actually, the problem is more about the original question (not the OP's but the one of the teacher), since, strictly speaking, you cannot deduce the momentum uncertainty from the uncertainty principle's lower bound. It is not saturated for this case, you can only give scaling arguments, which could be directly deduced from dimensional analysis.

Comment: It would be interesting to find what wavefunction actually minimizes momentum uncertainty in the infinite square well. I mean - not so interesting that I think someone should work that out.

Answer (score 1):

The uncertainty depends on the basis orientation. If the axes of your basis are parallel to the sides of the cube, then uncertainty in coordinates is equal to the length of the side. If the axes are parallel to the diagonal, then uncertainty in coordinates is equal to the length of the diagonal of the cube. If you need to find the minimal possible uncertainty in the velocity, then you want to find the maximum possible uncertainty in the coordinate, which corresponds to the length of the diagonal.